# Template Class with stream operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

I am trying to get a better understanding on some advanced staffs of C++. I am trying to understand `stream operator overloading` , `friend function` and `template` now. I am trying to learn all these things in a single code segment.

So, I am trying to implement a `template class` which will just contain an `array`, which I want to populate with `stream operator`. So,I came up with this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T, int L>
class TestClass
{
    private:
        T data[L];
    public:
        friend void operator>>(const istream&, const TestClass<T,L>&);
};

template<class T, int L>
void operator>>(const istream& in, const TestClass<T,L>& q)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        in >> q.data[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    TestClass<float, 3> Q;
    cin >> Q;

    return 0;
}
```

This is pretty easy code segment. But, I am getting following error on compilation

```
undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream const&, TestClass<float, 3> const&)'
```

with the following warning

```
warning: friend declaration 'void operator>>(const istream&, const TestClass<T, L>&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]|
```

I know, I am doing some rookie mistake, as I am pretty new to this things. It will be great if someone helps to run this successfully.

Comment: `void operator>>(const istream& in, const TestClass<T,L>& q)` -- How are you going to modify `q` if it is `const`?

Comment: off topic: usually `operator>>()` return a `std::istream` (the same `it`, in your case), not `void`

Comment: @max66, as far as my understanding till now, Its not mandatory to return an `istream`. is it ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati When it comes to operator overloading, there's a bunch of practices that are not technically mandatory, but you basically always want to do. Returning the stream from << and >> is one of those. cppreference has a whole page of these things.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati, While you're allowed to return void, it makes your class inconsistent with every other streamable class. `cin >> an_int >> a_test_class;` works, but `cin >> a_test_class >> an_int;` doesn't. That's really strange behaviour. In addition, the common `if (cin >>  foo)` pattern doesn't work with your class.

Comment: @chris, thanks . That's exactly what I was looking for to convince myself to always returning the `istream` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is two-fold:

1. Your `friend` function should also be a template
2. You are passing the `istream` and `TestClass` as const. Remove that

Here is updated code:

```
template<class T, int L>
class TestClass
{
    private:
        T data[L];
    public:
        template<class U, int M>
        friend void operator>>(istream&, TestClass<U,M>&);
};

template<class T, int L>
void operator>>(istream& in, TestClass<T,L>& q)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        in >> q.data[i];
    }
}
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UPRpEKI9CJGj6H92)

---

#### Edit: Other equally valid approaches

Slightly different syntax to declare the friend and everything will work [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J6iGQ3OcjgKSN7ct):

```
template<class T, int L>
class TestClass
{
    private:
        T data[L];
    public:
        friend void operator>> <>(istream&, TestClass&);
};
```

(Thanks @chris). This format (with the `<>`) differs from the above example in that the above is technically declaring *all* instantiations of `operator>>` to be a `friend` whereas this one only has a one-to-one relationship.

Alternatively you could include the definition along with the friend declaration [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/02bzkCt9fa5IZ6m4):

```
template<class T, int L>
class TestClass
{
    private:
        T data[L];
    public:
        friend void operator>>(istream& in, TestClass& q){
            for(int i = 0; i < L; i++)
            {
                in >> q.data[i];
            }       
        }
};
```

Comment: So, I need to to specify different `template` for my `friend function` while that is not the case `member` functions. right ?

Comment: @SurajeetBharati, Yes, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) has several scenarios and examples of friends. Without the template, you're saying there's a non-template free `operator>>(istream&, TestClass<float, 3>&)`. With the template, you're saying there's a free template and that every specialization of it is a friend (which is actually a bit overly permissive, since only the corresponding specialization needs to be a friend).

Comment: @SurajeetBharati: Right. Basically unless that friend function is also templated you are forced to write an overload for every instantiation of your `TestClass` [like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FJeso9VCDwYHzqWU).

Comment: @SurajeetBharati: Or you go with the slightly more complicated syntax like [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jAOhXiYR9sUgh5lT)